# DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE throws "PL/SQL: numeric or value error"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to test one of my functions in oracle pl/sql using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`. The problem I encounter is, that when I write a point number inside my function, I get the following error:

### Error

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numerischer oder Wertefehler: Fehler beim Konvertieren von Zeichen zu Zahl
ORA-06512: in Zeile 4 // line 4 is "v_net := pricecalculator(120.09)"
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

### This works

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Pricecalculator(net IN NUMBER, vat IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0.19)
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
        Result NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        Result := net * (1 + vat);
        RETURN Result;
    END;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
    v_net NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_net := Pricecalculator(120);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_net); // Prints (142.8)
END;
/
```

### This does not work (see error)

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
    v_net NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_net := Pricecalculator(120.09);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_net); // When I delete this, v_net gets compiled but I wont see the result
END;
/
```

I am new to oracle pl/sql and have zero clue why the second approach does not work.

Comment: [Seems to work OK...?](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f489eab76c7c254ac2745c9d51a28bd9) Checked in SQL Developer too (20.4, against a 12cR1 DB).

Comment: Doesn't work inside my sql_developer 0.o (20.2). My `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_net)` is shown grey

Comment: My guess: Your locales, check your sql **client** `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`. The database seems with dot decimal separator, i guess your client is going for comma decimal separator. Try `v_net := Pricecalculator(120,09);` in your PLSQL **client** bloc.

Comment: I can't write `Pricecalculator(120, 09)`, because then I would just change the `vat` parameter to 9 and the output would be 1200

Comment: @Zilog80 no; all of the arguments and variables are numbers, the NLS chars are only used for conversion to/from strings. Number literals always have to use a decimal point. `Pricecalculator(120,09)` will see that as two arguments, `net` of 120 and `vat` of 9. But you're right that it's that setting that's breaking it... in SQL Developer, at least.

Comment: @AlexPoole You right, it's only with conversion.  And the error points the `Pricecalculator` line not the `PUT_LINE`. But it's clearly related to the `PUT_LINE` as when OP removes it, it compiles. So i guess implicit conversion with `PUT_LINE` is a factor.

Comment: @Zilog80 I've compiled the code again and now it does not even work without DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE. Writing `Pricecalculator(120.88)` always throws an error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in SQL Developer. Looking at the statement log, your block is being converted to:

```
DECLARE SqlDevBind1Z_1 VARCHAR2(32767):=:SqlDevBind1ZInit1;  BEGIN DECLARE
    v_net NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_net := Pricecalculator(TO_NUMBER( SqlDevBind1Z_1));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_net);
END;
 :AUXSQLDBIND1:=SqlDevBind1Z_1;  END;
```

and this part:

```
TO_NUMBER( SqlDevBind1Z_1)
```

is doing an implicit conversion. That will use your NLS_NUMERIC_CHARTACTERS setting, as @Zilog80 suggested, so it's only a problem when that is set to `',.'` - i.e. with a comma as the decimal separator.

You can work around it by doing:

```
alter session set nls_numeric_characters = '.,'
```

but then your implicitly-converted output will be `142.9071` not `142,9071`. If you want the comma separator in the output you would then need an explicit conversion:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(v_net, '99990.9999', 'nls_numeric_characters='',.'''));
```

... except SQL Developer is also borking that; which is why you showed periods in your question, presumably. Hopefully that is what you want to see...

Comment: If i remember well, it's possible to specify `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARTACTERS` directly with the `TO_CHAR` function, the syntax: `TO_CHAR(number,format,'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')`.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you. Don't know how to explain this solution to my professor but yeah. SQL Developer is borderline stupid

Comment: @Zilog80 - thank you, yes, I'd started to show that and somehow posted with a bit of it missing.